# error : virPidFileAcquirePath:422 : Failed to acquire pid file '/run/user/1000/libvirt/libvirtd.pid': Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: centos, virtualization, virtualhost, virtual-machines, libvirt

Anyone have any ideas how to fix this? It looks like the computer is telling me libvirt has no VM to connect to.  I could be off the mark there.

I am starting to play with vitrd.  I am thinking of connecting to a a VM I spun up on my server using [boxes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/617688/boxes-centos7-where-is-the-value) on CentOS7.

```
 error : virPidFileAcquirePath:422 : Failed to acquire pid file '/run/user/1000/libvirt/libvirtd.pid': Resource temporarily unavailable

    [orca@orcacomputers ~]$ systemctl status libvirtd
● libvirtd.service - Virtualization daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/libvirtd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2020-11-01 15:15:47 PST; 1 day 4h ago
     Docs: man:libvirtd(8)
           https://libvirt.org
 Main PID: 1770 (libvirtd)
    Tasks: 19 (limit: 32768)
   Memory: 10.1M
   CGroup: /system.slice/libvirtd.service
           ├─1770 /usr/sbin/libvirtd
           ├─2418 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --conf-file=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.conf --leasefile-ro --dhcp-script=/usr/libexec/libvirt_leaseshelper
           └─2419 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --conf-file=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.conf --leasefile-ro --dhcp-script=/usr/libexec/libvirt_leaseshelper

Nov 02 13:44:41 orcacomputers.orcainbox dnsmasq-dhcp[2418]: DHCPACK(virbr0) 192.168.122.48 52:54:00:39:15:6b
Nov 02 13:51:14 orcacomputers.orcainbox libvirtd[1770]: 2020-11-02 21:51:14.332+0000: 1770: error : virNetSocketReadWire:1806 : End of file while reading data: Input/output error
Nov 02 14:05:06 orcacomputers.orcainbox dnsmasq-dhcp[2418]: DHCPREQUEST(virbr0) 192.168.122.48 52:54:00:39:15:6b
Nov 02 14:05:06 orcacomputers.orcainbox dnsmasq-dhcp[2418]: DHCPACK(virbr0) 192.168.122.48 52:54:00:39:15:6b
Nov 02 14:25:11 orcacomputers.orcainbox dnsmasq-dhcp[2418]: DHCPREQUEST(virbr0) 192.168.122.48 52:54:00:39:15:6b
Nov 02 14:25:11 orcacomputers.orcainbox dnsmasq-dhcp[2418]: DHCPACK(virbr0) 192.168.122.48 52:54:00:39:15:6b
Nov 02 14:50:50 orcacomputers.orcainbox dnsmasq-dhcp[2418]: DHCPREQUEST(virbr0) 192.168.122.48 52:54:00:39:15:6b
Nov 02 14:50:50 orcacomputers.orcainbox dnsmasq-dhcp[2418]: DHCPACK(virbr0) 192.168.122.48 52:54:00:39:15:6b
Nov 02 15:18:21 orcacomputers.orcainbox dnsmasq-dhcp[2418]: DHCPREQUEST(virbr0) 192.168.122.48 52:54:00:39:15:6b
Nov 02 15:18:21 orcacomputers.orcainbox dnsmasq-dhcp[2418]: DHCPACK(virbr0) 192.168.122.48 52:54:00:39:15:6b

    [orca@orcacomputers ~]$ libvirtd -v
2020-11-03 03:27:35.145+0000: 30042: info : libvirt version: 4.5.0, package: 33.el7_8.1 (CentOS BuildSystem <http://bugs.centos.org>, 2020-05-12-16:25:35, x86-01.bsys.centos.org)
2020-11-03 03:27:35.145+0000: 30042: info : hostname: orcacomputers.orcainbox
2020-11-03 03:27:35.145+0000: 30042: info : virObjectNew:248 : OBJECT_NEW: obj=0x5649c93d1eb0 classname=virAccessManager
2020-11-03 03:27:35.145+0000: 30042: info : virObjectNew:248 : OBJECT_NEW: obj=0x5649c93cfea0 classname=virAccessManager
2020-11-03 03:27:35.145+0000: 30042: info : virObjectRef:382 : OBJECT_REF: obj=0x5649c93d1eb0
2020-11-03 03:27:35.145+0000: 30042: info : virObjectUnref:344 : OBJECT_UNREF: obj=0x5649c93d1eb0
2020-11-03 03:27:35.145+0000: 30042: error : virPidFileAcquirePath:422 : Failed to acquire pid file '/run/user/1000/libvirt/libvirtd.pid': Resource temporarily unavailable
2020-11-03 03:27:35.145+0000: 30042: info : virNetlinkEventServiceStopAll:865 : stopping all netlink event services
2020-11-03 03:27:35.145+0000: 30042: info : virNetlinkEventServiceStop:828 : stopping netlink event service
2020-11-03 03:27:35.145+0000: 30042: info : virNetlinkEventServiceStop:828 : stopping netlink event service
2020-11-03 03:27:35.145+0000: 30042: info : virNetlinkEventServiceStop:828 : stopping netlink event service
2020-11-03 03:27:35.145+0000: 30042: info : virNetlinkEventServiceStop:828 : stopping netlink event service
2020-11-03 03:27:35.145+0000: 30042: info : virNetlinkEventServiceStop:828 : stopping netlink event service
2020-11-03 03:27:35.145+0000: 30042: info : virNetlinkEventServiceStop:828 : stopping netlink event service
2020-11-03 03:27:35.145+0000: 30042: info : virNetlinkEventServiceStop:828 : stopping netlink event service
2020-11-03 03:27:35.145+0000: 30042: info : virNetlinkEventServiceStop:828 : stopping netlink event service
2020-11-03 03:27:35.145+0000: 30042: info : virNetlinkEventServiceStop:828 : stopping netlink event service
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check that libvirtd was running on your system using command

```
ps -ef | grep libvirtd
```

move your pid file using command

```
mv /var/run/libvirtd.pid /var/run/libvirtd.pid.old
```

stop libvirtd service using command

```
systemctl stop libvirtd.service
```

and start again using command

```
systemctl start libvirtd.service
```